# itext-paulo jar wrong(new) version is getting downloaded fom maven

Tags: java, dependencies, pdf-generation, maven-3

please see the parent Pom As per Pom Itext refers to 155 version but it is getting downloaded 2.17 js3.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fe</groupId>
    <artifactId>assesshub</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>micro-commons</module>
        <module>microadmin</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <postgresql.version>9.2-1002.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
        <core-renderer.version>R8pre2</core-renderer.version>
        <jersey-spring.version>1.10</jersey-spring.version>
        <jersey-core.version>1.10</jersey-core.version>
        <jersey-client.version>1.10</jersey-client.version>
        <jersey-server.version>1.10</jersey-server.version>
        <jersey-json.version>1.10</jersey-json.version>
        <jackson-core-asl.version>1.8.3</jackson-core-asl.version>
        <jackson-mapper-asl.version>1.8.3</jackson-mapper-asl.version>
        <jackson-jaxrs.version>1.8.3</jackson-jaxrs.version>
        <jackson-xc.version>1.8.3</jackson-xc.version>
        <glassfish.jersey-container-servlet.version>2.0</glassfish.jersey-container-servlet.version>
        <glassfish.jersey-client.version>2.0</glassfish.jersey-client.version>
        <glassfish.jersey-media-multipart.version>2.0</glassfish.jersey-media-multipart.version>

        <apache.poi.version>3.10-FINAL</apache.poi.version>
        <apache.poi-ooxml.version>3.10-FINAL</apache.poi-ooxml.version>
        <apache.poi-ooxml-schemas.version>3.10-FINAL</apache.poi-ooxml-schemas.version>

        <xmlbeans-maven-plugin.version>2.3.3</xmlbeans-maven-plugin.version>
        <dwr.version>3.0-local</dwr.version>
        <commons-validator.version>1.4.1</commons-validator.version>
        <spring-modules-validation.version>0.8</spring-modules-validation.version>
        <spring-version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <aspectjweaver.version>1.8.1</aspectjweaver.version>
        <aspectjrt.version>1.8.1</aspectjrt.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>

        <html2image.version>0.9</html2image.version>
        <itext-paulo.version>155</itext-paulo.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-math.version>1.2</commons-math.version>

        <tomcat-maven-plugin.version>1.1</tomcat-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-glassfish-plugin.version>2.1</maven-glassfish-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.17</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.source.version>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.source.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.target.version>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.target.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.webflow.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

        <hibernate-core.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <net.sf.ehcache>2.6.9</net.sf.ehcache>

        <micro-commons.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</micro-commons.version>

        <assesshub-commons.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</assesshub-commons.version>
        <rulesengine.version>1.0</rulesengine.version>
        <code-simulator-commons.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</code-simulator-commons.version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.31</mysql-connector-java.version>
        <commons-configuration.version>1.10</commons-configuration.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.5.0</dbunit.version>
        <javax.servlet.api>3.1.0</javax.servlet.api>
        <commons.httpclient>3.1</commons.httpclient>
        <jsoup>1.7.3</jsoup>
        <org.owasp.esapi>2.1.0</org.owasp.esapi>
        <swisseph.version>1.0</swisseph.version>

        <javamelody.version>1.57.0</javamelody.version>
        <jrobin.version>1.5.9</jrobin.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.23</freemarker.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.4</lombok.version>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <gson.version>2.2.2</gson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-pool}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ecs</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecs</artifactId>
                <version>${ecs.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.terracotta.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>tim-async-processing</artifactId>
                <version>${tim-async-processing.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.terracotta.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>tim-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${tim-annotations.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.terracotta.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>tim-concurrent-collections</artifactId>
                <version>${tim-concurrent-collections.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.terracotta.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>terracotta-api</artifactId>
                <version>${terracotta-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
                <version>${jfreechart.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>${commons.logging}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.commons.dbcp2}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <version>${xstream.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>${jettison.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
                <version>${displaytag.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jsp-api.version}</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>${jstl.version}</version>
                <!-- scope>provided</scope -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles-core.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles-api.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles-jsp.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
                <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
                <version>${core-renderer.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- web services dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-spring.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-json.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-server.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-core-asl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-mapper-asl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-jaxrs.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-xc.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- ends here -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.poi-ooxml.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.poi-ooxml-schemas.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${xmlbeans-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
                <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
                <version>${dwr.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-modules-validation.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
                <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectjweaver.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>${quartz.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>gui.ava</groupId>
                <artifactId>html2image</artifactId>
                <version>${html2image.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                <artifactId>itext-paulo</artifactId>
                <version>${itext-paulo.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-math</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-math.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Starts -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring ends -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
                <version>${net.sf.ehcache}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Hibernate EHCache API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fe</groupId>
                <artifactId>micro-commons</artifactId>
                <version>${micro-commons.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>${paypal.rest-api-sdk.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-configuration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
                <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.api}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>${commons.httpclient}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>${jsoup}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
                <version>${org.owasp.esapi}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fe.ah.astro</groupId>
                <artifactId>astro-swisseph</artifactId>
                <version>${swisseph.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
                <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
                <version>${javamelody.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jrobin</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrobin</artifactId>
                <version>${jrobin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>${gson.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven-compiler-plugin.source.version}</source>
                        <target>${maven-compiler-plugin.target.version}</target>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>analyze</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>validate</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-forge</id>
            <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>teracotta</id>
            <url>http://repo.terracotta.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

As we can see  version refers to 155 but it downloads 2.17 j3 version why?
is there something that i am missing it should refer to 1.3 version jar but it is pointing to 2.17 and my already written implementations are not working?

Comment: There is no technical support for iText versions that are past End-Of-Life. That particular version is over a decade old. Strangely enough I also see iText version 5.4.0 in your POM. I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: com.lowagie.text.* the problem is with this jar

Comment: you can learn a lot from `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Yes. Run the command `mvn dependency:tree` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Replace all `com.lowagie.text.*` with `com.itextpdf.text.*` and your code will still work.

Comment: mvn dependency:tree gives protocol error becacse there is no settings.xml prsent in m2 repository

Comment: That's another problem, unrelated to your question.

Comment: Itext 2.17-js3 might be a transitive dependency of jasperreports.

Comment: yes it is but not in com.lowagie.itext.2.1.7.js3.itext-2.1.7.js3.jar
 it is in com.lowagie.itext.1.3.itext-1.3.jar
and my imports are referring to new one 
is there any problem in eclipse import/because eclipse is not giving me any option to import old jar method.

Comment: If you have multiple itext versions before 5.0 in your class path, they'll conflict. The same is true for multiple 5.x versions and for multiple 7.x versions. Unless you use a technology like OSGi or you do some class leader acrobatics, you cannot use multiple conflicting versions of the same library in your project.

Comment: ok, that means i have to take long way and change the methods implementation and do testing for pdf.I was avoiding that that thing, but thanks I appreciate your efforts at least now i know there is nothing workaround